# What can be issue with Tomcat that it starts in RUN mode but in debug mode it hangs forever?

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

I am using STS(eclipse) and facing a weird issue with Tomcat. It was running fine and all of a sudden it started giving issues. Firstly it responded very slowly and after it did not respond at all in debug mode. While it runs fine when is started in RUN mode but when debugging it waits for something after -

```
May 15, 2013 9:03:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 15, 2013 9:03:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
May 15, 2013 9:03:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

The server is stuck forever, seems like it is asking for something from somewhere or so. I did many things like - deleting the server and setting the whole thing again, took a different Tomcat. I did not change any set up for sure.

Comment: Do you have any breakpoints set?

Comment: got it fixed. thanks. removed all the breakpoints and every thing is working fine. weird though, this behavior is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any breakpoints set, this could cause the server to pause during startup.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have any breakpoints in the declaration of a method

```
public void myMethod( ParamType myParameter ){ //breakpoint in this line
...
}
```

You would see the break point marked as [entry] in the breakpoints view in Debug perspective instead of [line: XX] as breakspoints inside implementation are shown.

Disable that breakpoint and try to start server in Debug. This worked for me, hope this helps someone.